# How is this specific design effect achieved?

Tags: html, css

On this site, http://kickpoint.ca/, there is a little red triangle underneath the main red section at the top

[image]

I cant for the life of me work out how it is done. I've used Chrome dev tools and cant see where it is defined.

Anyone know how it is achieved or if there is a standard way of achieving this effect?

Comment: This is all CSS3 with borders and the :before and :after pseudos.

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Look into the use of psuedo element "after", and css rotate.

Comment: http://www.css3shapes.com/ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Triangles.

**CSS**

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

---

**Resource**

More info can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Comment: Yup, and more specifically its attached to a pseudo-element, which is visible in Chrome's dev tools towards the bottom of the Matched CSS Rules pane.

Answer (score 1):

It uses CSS to make triangles.  The basic concept of creating a triangle is to set the border of `div` on one side to form the base.  The adjacent border is left blank and the borders perpendicular to the base are set to `transparent`.  A good explanation of CSS triangles can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

**HTML**

```
<div class="pointer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pointer{
    width: 100px;
}
.pointer .inner {
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}

.pointer .arrow{
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    width: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JYM8w/